# Dropbox.API Nuget update to 3.0.1 gives CS0012 compilation error for System.Object on ASP.Net MVC 5 view

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, dropbox, dropbox-api

I updated the Dropbox.API Nuget-package to 3.0.1 from 2.3.6 and now I'm getting the error

> The type System.Object is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.

The following is marked red under source of error, but it's NOT my code

> Line 31:     public class _Page_Views_Dropbox_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage {

I tested to run the code with 2.3.6 just before updating and it all worked.

The compilation information box says

> Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1038.0
>
> for C# 5
>
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

I have .Net 4.6.1 as target framework though.

Is this a bug in Dropbox's package so I should downgrade until they have fixed it or do I need to change something with code relating to `MembersListResult`?

**Update**
Dropbox has now fixed this issue with the update to package version 3.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following information http://www.lyalin.com/2014/04/25/the-type-system-object-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-reference-mvc-pcl-issue/
I tried adding only `<add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />` under `<assemblies>`. I skipped adding `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">` since that feels related to the older framework that I'm not using.

It's now working, but after reading this from Microsoft, it looks like Dropbox did something wrong when compiling the Nuget-package https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2971005